# How to add complex header/footer to list report in Cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

I want to build a list report with complex footer and header, the issue is: if the column number of footer is bigger than the list body.it seems difficult to add more column to the footer. If I add list footer, the column number is just as same as the list body, I can merge,but can't split a cell. Please tell me how to achieve this. I know I can add a table to the tail of that list, and fix the width of list and table, but I don't think it is a good idea, because the table wound not repeat in every page. And sometimes needs to merge celles cross rows or columns.

[image]

Comment: You can definitely add more than one row of headers/hooters. In your case, I'm confused as you correctly state you can add a table in one of the cells, but then "it would not repeat on every page." No table footers repeat on any page. Page footers do. What sort of data are you trying to put in the header/footer? Are you confusing the list footer with the page footer?

Comment: "if the column number of footer is bigger than the list body.it seems difficult to add more column to the footer. " This is what I want.The row is not a problem.You can see the pic I posted,the footer's column is 6,but the list's column is 3. I don't know how to do this in cognos.